# I have a plane equation in Ax By Cz d=0 form. Now using mouse points i want to draw on that plane.

Tags: c#, opengl

I have  a plane equation in Ax+By+Cz d=0 form. I am able to draw a quad on that plane. Now using mouse points i want to draw on that plane. For that i am trying to get a point on the plane from the mouse point. For that i am making a ray from the camera to the plane passing that mouse point. But when i am trying to render it is not positioning on correct location.

I am drawing the quad by this way:
                OpenGL.glPushMatrix();

```
            OpenGL.glMultMatrix(mTransform);

            OpenGL.glColor(Color.FromArgb(60, Color.BlanchedAlmond));

            OpenGL.glPushMatrix();
            Matrix4 transform = Matrix4.Identity;
            Quaternion planeRotation = Vector3.ZAxis.GetRotationTo(mMarkUpPlane.Normal);
            Vector3 planeOrigin = mMarkUpPlane.Normal * -mMarkUpPlane.D;

            transform.Matrix3 = planeRotation.GetRotationMatrix();
            transform.Translation = planeOrigin;
            OpenGL.glMultMatrix(transform);

            const double PlaneWidth = 1500;

            OpenGL.glBegin(OpenGL.GL_QUADS);

            OpenGL.glVertex3d(PlaneWidth, PlaneWidth, 0.0);
            OpenGL.glVertex3d(PlaneWidth, -PlaneWidth, 0.0);
            OpenGL.glVertex3d(-PlaneWidth, -PlaneWidth, 0.0);
            OpenGL.glVertex3d(-PlaneWidth, PlaneWidth, 0.0);

            OpenGL.glEnd();
            OpenGL.glPopMatrix();
            OpenGL.glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Why the gratuitous horizontal whitespace?

Comment: I am not getting about what you are telling gratuitous horizontal whitespace? Can you please specfy?

Comment: You have everything indented by 12 spaces for no discernible reason.

Comment: If the question is not clear then should i restate that?